# XML task, how to save buffer?

Tags: xml, ant, save, buffer, xmltask

i'm useing the XML task in ANT to copy siome XML stuff.

```
<xmltask source="test.xml">
            <copy path="starttag/Checktag[@id='123']" buffer="test"/>

        </xmltask>
```

This part of code copies everything which is between the Checktag with the id 123. My only problem now is that i really don't know how to save the buffer test to a new xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from [the XMLTask documentation](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/):

> ```
> <xmltask sourcebuffer="servlet" output="servlet.xml">
> ```
>
> reads from the previously populated buffer servlet and writes to
>   [servlet.xml]